# My JButton is not displaying consistently, it is not the same size and not in the same spot

Tags: java, jbutton

JButton two displays in 2 places and  sizes, there are two classes

It is not consistent with size and location
Please help, thanks
The code is down below in two sections

final public class ChessMain {

```
JFrame frame; 

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new ChessMain().go();
}

private void go() {
    frame = new JFrame("Test");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  //  Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
    frame.setContentPane(new DrawPanelChess ());
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

    Icon warnIcon = new ImageIcon("white_King_Chess.png");
    JButton button2 = new JButton(warnIcon);  
    button2.setLayout(null);
    button2.setBounds(100,0, 100, 100); 
    frame.add(button2);


 }
```

}

class DrawPanelChess extends JPanel {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 9166938856558245300L;
```

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

```
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());    


        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);

        {//row 1                        
        g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth() / 8, this.getHeight() / 8);                         
        g.fillRect(this.getWidth() / 4, 0, this.getWidth() / 8, this.getHeight() / 8);                         
        g.fillRect(this.getWidth() / 2, 0, this.getWidth() / 8, this.getHeight() / 8);                         
        g.fillRect(this.getWidth() / 8 * 6, 0, this.getWidth() / 8, this.getHeight() / 8);                         
        }

        {//row 2                        
        g.fillRect(this.getWidth() / 8, this.getHeight() / 8, this.getWidth() / 8, this.getHeight() / 8);                         
        g.fillRect(this.getWidth() / 8 * 3, this.getHeight() / 8, this.getWidth() / 8, this.getHeight() / 8);                        
        g.fillRect(this.getWidth() / 8 * 5, this.getHeight() / 8, this.getWidth() / 8, this.getHeight() / 8);                         
        g.fillRect(this.getWidth() / 8 * 7, this.getHeight() / 8, this.getWidth() / 8, this.getHeight() / 8);                         
        }

        {//row 3                        
        g.fillRect(0, this.getHeight() / 4, this.getWidth() / 8, this.getHeight() / 8);                         
        g.fillRect(this.getWidth() / 4, this.getHeight() / 4, this.getWidth() / 8, this.getHeight() / 8);                         
        g.fillRect(this.getWidth() / 2, this.getHeight() / 4, this.getWidth() / 8, this.getHeight() / 8);                         
        g.fillRect(this.getWidth() / 8 * 6, this.getHeight() / 4, this.getWidth() / 8, this.getHeight() / 8);                         
        }

        {//row 4                        
        g.fillRect(this.getWidth() / 8, this.getHeight() / 8 * 3, this.getWidth() / 8, this.getHeight() / 8);                         
        g.fillRect(this.getWidth() / 8 * 3, this.getHeight() / 8 * 3, this.getWidth() / 8, this.getHeight() / 8);                        
        g.fillRect(this.getWidth() / 8 * 5, this.getHeight() / 8 * 3, this.getWidth() / 8, this.getHeight() / 8);                         
        g.fillRect(this.getWidth() / 8 * 7, this.getHeight() / 8 * 3, this.getWidth() / 8, this.getHeight() / 8);                         
        }

        {//row 5                        
        g.fillRect(0, this.getHeight() / 2, this.getWidth() / 8, this.getHeight() / 8);                         
        g.fillRect(this.getWidth() / 4, this.getHeight() / 2, this.getWidth() / 8, this.getHeight() / 8);                         
        g.fillRect(this.getWidth() / 2, this.getHeight() / 2, this.getWidth() / 8, this.getHeight() / 8);                         
        g.fillRect(this.getWidth() / 8 * 6, this.getHeight() / 2, this.getWidth() / 8, this.getHeight() / 8);                         
        }

        {//row 6                        
        g.fillRect(this.getWidth() / 8, this.getHeight() / 8 * 5, this.getWidth() / 8, this.getHeight() / 8);                         
        g.fillRect(this.getWidth() / 8 * 3, this.getHeight() / 8 * 5, this.getWidth() / 8, this.getHeight() / 8);                        
        g.fillRect(this.getWidth() / 8 * 5, this.getHeight() / 8 * 5, this.getWidth() / 8, this.getHeight() / 8);                         
        g.fillRect(this.getWidth() / 8 * 7, this.getHeight() / 8 * 5, this.getWidth() / 8, this.getHeight() / 8);                         
        }

        {//row 7                        
        g.fillRect(0, this.getHeight() / 8 * 6, this.getWidth() / 8, this.getHeight() / 8);                         
        g.fillRect(this.getWidth() / 4, this.getHeight() / 8 * 6, this.getWidth() / 8, this.getHeight() / 8);                         
        g.fillRect(this.getWidth() / 2, this.getHeight() / 8 * 6, this.getWidth() / 8, this.getHeight() / 8);                         
        g.fillRect(this.getWidth() / 8 * 6, this.getHeight() / 8 * 6, this.getWidth() / 8, this.getHeight() / 8);                         
        }

        {//row 8                        
        g.fillRect(this.getWidth() / 8, this.getHeight() / 8 * 7, this.getWidth() / 8, this.getHeight() / 8);                         
        g.fillRect(this.getWidth() / 8 * 3, this.getHeight() / 8 * 7, this.getWidth() / 8, this.getHeight() / 8);                        
        g.fillRect(this.getWidth() / 8 * 5, this.getHeight() / 8 * 7, this.getWidth() / 8, this.getHeight() / 8);                         
        g.fillRect(this.getWidth() / 8 * 7, this.getHeight() / 8 * 7, this.getWidth() / 8, this.getHeight() / 8);                         
        }

       // System.out.println("\u2654");

        repaint();
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

It seems your adding the button to the frame after you add your DrawPanelChess JPanel as the contentPane for the frame. It re-positions itself when you change the frame size. Not a great work around for the future if you intend to add more components but to avoid it for the time being add

```
frame.setResizable(false);
```

I would also suggest using something like a GridBagLayout to specify where you want it to position itself along with the chess panel.